# Tenure track position after campus interview on Apr 19

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, interview, engineering

I had a campus interview on Apr 19, and there are other two candidates were interviewed after me in the same week. I sent out a thank you note to the search committee after I finished the interview. I believe I did a good job in the interview, especially for the research talk part. One of faculties told me that it was a good presentation and good job. I received an email from the chair two days ago and he told me that they are working on finalizing the candidate and asked me to send him the degree, transcript, and EIT designation. So, I was wondering does that a good sign to me? Am I the top candidate to them?

Thank you!

Comment: that is not an answerable question, as we can't read mind of the appointment committee. Is there a problem you need help solving?

Comment: Here is yet another classic opinion-based question that has not only been left open, but answered. Why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee, but it seems that you place highly, at least. Do what they ask and hope for the best.

My best guess is that unless the required documentation shows something critically wrong, then you are likely to get an offer. But it is their process, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking: asking you for more details means that you’re definitely being seriously considered. Rejection letters are usually short and to the point; no one would ask for more details if you’re not under consideration.

Are you the top candidate? It’s actually likely: they’re asking for administrative information which is likely needed to verify your credentials, something that’s usually done at a later stage of the hiring process. Of course, you’ll know soon enough!